# What determines whether IPv4 address or IPv6 address will be used on sites?

Tags: networking, ip, ipv6

When I access my Facebook, for example, sometimes my current connection is listed using a IPv4 address, and sometimes, a IPv6 address. What is responsible for this choice?

Comment: Two separate DNS requests may be being issued, one for IPv4 and one for IPv6 (which isn't uncommon in dual stack scenarios). After receiving the responses, a client will likely prefer IPv6 over IPv4. However, if the client cannot use IPv6 for some reason, any valid IPv4 address may be used to connect instead.

Comment: What are the reasons that a cliente can not use IPv6?

Comment: The primary reason would likely be that the server response is too slow (or entirely non-existent).